# Fundamental Theorem of Analysis: Help in understanding steps of proof.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Statement (Fundamental Theorem of Analysis):
Let $f: I \rightarrow \mathbb C$ be continuous on $I \subseteq \mathbb R$ and let $a \in I$. Define $$F(x) := \int^x_a f(t) \, dt, \ x\in I.$$
Then $F$ is differentiable in $I$ and $F^{'}(x) = f(x) \ \forall x \in I$.

Proof:
Let $x_0$ be arbitrary. Suppose $x_0$ is an inner point of $I$ and $[x_0-r, x_0+r] \subseteq I$. For every $h \in \mathbb R: |h| \le r$ we have $$F(x_0+h)-F(x_0)=\int^{x_0+h}_a f(t) \,dt - \int^{x_0}_a f(t) \, dt = \int^{x_0+h}_{x_0} f(t) \,dt.$$

**(Why is this true ? If $h < 0$ does the last integral even makes sense ?)
(Also how can $F(x)$ be defined for $x < a$ ? - then the integral is undefined ?)**

Now assume $h>0$.

Thus $$F(x_0+h)-F(x_0)-hf(x_0)= \int^{x_0+h}_{x_0} f(t)-f(x_0) \, dt$$ which imply $$|\frac {F(x_0+h)-F(x_0)} h -f(x_0)| \le  \frac 1 h \int^{x_0+h}_{x_0} |f(t)-f(x_0)| dt.$$

Since $f$ is continuous we can choose $r\ge \delta >0: |f(y)-f(x_0)|\le \epsilon$ for $|y-x_0| \le \delta$ so $$|\frac {F(x_0+h)-F(x_0)} h -f(x_0)| \le  \frac 1 h \int^{x_0+h}_{x_0} \epsilon \ dt = \epsilon$$

**By similar reasoning one can conclude the same for $h < 0$ which imply $F(x)$ is differentiable. But I don't see how this is done for $h <0$ . Could someone please help me out.**

Comment: Even if the upper limit is a number smaller than the lower limit, the integral still makes sense (as long as the corresponding intervals lie within the function's domain of definition, of course). Remember that $$\int\limits_a^b=-\int\limits_b^a$$

Comment: I have only seen this stated in a basic calculus book, but never in my book on integration theory. Can one prove this equality, or is it only by definition ?

Comment: @user111854 It's by definition.

Comment: Well, it can be a definition but, as Stewart remarks in his "Calculus", it follows from the appropiately defined Riemann sums.

Comment: But a partition is only defined for $[a,b]$ where $a < b$ ? It is not defined for $[b,a]$ ?